# Maven multi-module project and webapp project

Tags: java, maven

I have two questions about maven project structure:

1) I am creating a maven multi-module project and would like to know if I can put all the common dependencies of the modules in the parent pom? Is that the right way to do?

2) If I am creating a maven webapp project that contains all web.xml and JSP files, where should the web controllers, listeners and model objects be residing? In a separate maven jar project or in the same webapp project?

Answer (score 1):

1) Read up on the difference between `dependencyManagement` and `dependencies`. Putting all common dependencies in the parent POM will work, but it's likely to cause spurious dependencies when you add a new module.

`dependencyManagement` is recommended. You can specify all versions and exclusions in a central place, and then it's enough to specify `groupId` and `artifactId` for each dependency of each module.

2) Java sources directly related to the web layer usually go into the `war` module (unless you want to reuse them for a different project, then it's better to factor them out into a separate `jar`).